# Determine if received data is PostScript or PCL

Tags: printing, postscript, printer-control-language

I have a service that receives printer data via tcp/ip.  When the data is received, is there reliable, efficient way to examine the data stream and determine if the data is PostScript vs PCL data?  For example, are there characters I could look for at the beginning of the data stream to indicate the format?

Comment: Are your printing clients somehow 'consistent' in their submitted PostScript and/or PCL data structures? If yes, it may be very easy to determine the file type. If no, it involves much more effort...

Comment: Yes, they are consistent.  I ended up using a combination of the information in the answer below.  I first search for the PJL ENTER LANGUAGE command.  If I locate that, I make the determination based on that value.  Otherwise, I search for %!PS because all of the PostScript data should adhere to the DSC conventions.  If I still cannot make the determination, I just default to PCL because that is what the vast majority of the clients are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Postscript data must begin with "%!ps" or "%!PS"  - it may be a longer readable string like "%!PS-Adobe-3.0" - but that is basically this.

Most likely PCL have a similar signature - I remember seeing it in the past.

Comment: You would need to watch out for PJL commands prior to the start of the PCL or PostScript. If you do have PJL commands at the beginning you will often see a PJL command telling you what the data type is with the following "@PJL ENTER LANGUAGE=PCLXL"

Comment: While specific implementions may require this, the `/%!.*/` string is not a requirement of the Postscript Language, per PRLM. It is part of the DSC conventions.

Comment: What about the ENTER LANGUAGE command?  Can that be relied on?

Comment: ***IF*** the ENTER LANGUAGE PJL command appears at all, then it should be rather reliable -- and the very next line should be the beginning of the data (PostScript or PCL).

Comment: I'd say that more than 99% of all real-world PostScript print files out there will use the introductionary magic string `!%` (or the b0rken Windoze `^D!%` variant of it). However, luser droog is right about this not being a hard requirement as per the official Adobe 'red book' *PostScript Reference and Language Manual*... @jsbueno: Note, that your listed `!%PS` and `!%ps` and `!%PS-Adobe-3.0` are even less a requirement than `!%` is (the latter one being a requirement if a file is supposed to follow the Adobe Document Structuring Conventions (DSC) version 3)...

Comment: Darn it! I got the letters mixed up, and then @pipitas expanded my mixed-up letters! It's called the *Postscript Language Reference Manual* or *PLRM*.

Answer (score 1):

I would probably just count the number of escape characters in the file. PCL will have gobs of them. Postscript will have gobs of % signs. That isn't a perfect solution, but it's dead simple and I'll bet it would actually be quite reliable.

The only "real" way I can see doing this is to actually parse the PCL and parse the postscript and see which one works.

Answer (score 1):

I'll add my 2¢.

Like others have mentioned here, your first stab at programmatically identifying the document would be to look at the first two characters.  If it starts with `%!`, it is PostScript, if it starts with an escape character (hex `1B`, oct `033`, ascii `27`), as very likely PCL will start with PCL commands, then it is PCL.  This will likely resolve 99% of the documents you need to process.  If it still isn't known, then you can search the document for a `showpage` string.  If it's PostScript, it has to have a showpage to render the page.  If you can't find one, and if there are any escape characters in the file, you know it is PCL, and you can err on the side of PCL if there is no showpage, and there is no escape characters, because raw text files are valid PCL and printers can blort them out as they come.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [PCL 5 General Printing FAQs](https://developers.hp.com/system/files/PCL_5_General_Printing_FAQs.pdf) PCL files should start with ESC "E". I assume another ESC sequence must follow. So my guess is that files starting with bytes 1B 45 1B are most likely PCL files.
This leaves PCL files unrecognized which don't adhere to this rule.

In my use case it's macOS that always produces PCL with the ESC E at the beginning.